# How to Verify Restassured api responses

Tags: java, json

I have two txt files which have thousands of end points. I have to verify response of every end point from each file and verify their output as below:

File 1 : line 1 & File 2 : line 1, File 1 : line 2 & File 2 : line 2, File 1 : line 3 & File 2 : line
3 and so on

output
`https://reqres.in/api/users/3` not equals `https://reqres.in/api/users/1`
`https://reqres.in/api/users/2` equals `https://reqres.in/api/users/2`
`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1` equals `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`

I must use multi thread in order to run end points simultaneously. I did it and response was received properly however, I am unable to verify responses for each end point.

Can someone help me how to do it

Comment: Have you already tried something? Share your code

Comment: public class ResponseTest {

 @Test
 public void testRespPass() throws IOException {

  FileComparator fileComparator = new FileComparator();

  List<String> file1Data = fileComparator
    .getFileData("C:\\File_EndPoint1.txt");
  List<String> file2Data = fileComparator
    .getFileData("C:\\File_EndPoint2.txt");

  // file1Data and file2Data size should be equal need to check the conditions
  // then only we can proceed further
  fileComparator.compareFileData(file1Data, file2Data);
 }
}

Comment: @Alex, I m unable to post my code. I am new and let me know how to share my complete code

Comment: paste your code inside ``` ```

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I had fixed the issue